# Can I access my Oracle DataBase From Home?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to access my Oracle DataBase at home so that I could work weekends, etc. I talked to my database administrator and all he had to do was add my home IP to his records, and I was allowed access.

Comment: First thing you need to do is talk to your boss about it...

Comment: you should talk to your IT infrastructure team. Probably you have VPN there or something so that you'll be able to connect remotely. In general I believe this is not a real question and it shouldn't be posted here...

Comment: Good Point. I should be able to get the directions internally. Sorry for posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OTN download license allows us to install the full suite of Oracle software, providing it is for the purposes of self-education.

So really it depends on what you mean by "play around with queries from home".  If you're doing work you need a database licence; if you're teaching yourself about Oracle you don't.

The bigger issue is data security: the chances are you're not allowed to have the *data* on a laptop.  Follow the news to understand why this is a bad idea.  If you want to teach yourself Oracle there are lots of [publicly available data sets](http://www.infochimps.com/datasets) we can download from the internet.

Comment: That makes sense...I really just wanted it to teach myself. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [exp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm#1013411) or [data pump export](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#i1007466)(10g onward) utility to unload data and metadata of your schema (user) into an OS file (dump file), bring it home and use [imp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1656) or [data pump import](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#i1007653) (10g onward) utility to import those unloaded previously data to a new schema.

Comment: At home, you can use ORACLE XE.  Make sure it is the same version (or close) as the one from where you are exporting your data.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is small you can also use Oracle SQL Developer to export the scripts for the schema and the Insert statements for the data.
This is also possible in third-party tools such as TOAD.